# Why is my SQL query trying to convert an nvarchar value to int? (using CONTAINSTABLE())

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am trying to get the FullText Search working in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have been working with our admin and we believe we have a catalog with indexes successfully set up. Now, I'm trying to query the indexed table using FullText functions

This works without a problem:

```
select *
from mPages
where contains(bodytext, ' "a dog" ')
```

However, when I try to get rank values by using `containstable()`, I get an error.

```
select mPages.bodytext, KEY_TBL.RANK
from mPages
     INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE(mPages, bodyText,
                    'dog') AS KEY_TBL
     ON mPages.pageID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC;
```

Error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'About' to data type int.
```

The "About" value is in a column called `pagename`. I don't understand how to get this error to go away.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably complaining about this line:

```
ON mPages.pageID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

Assuming `pageID` is an `int`, it will try to convert the `key` to an `int` so the columns can be compared.  The conversion is not going as planned.

Comment: I am confused. No where did I tell it to use `pagename` as the key. is there a way to manually set the key to be `pageID`?

Comment: @quakkels: Check the ` TableFulltextKeyColumn` property on your full-text index.  You can do so in SQL through the view `sys.fulltext_indexes`

Comment: I see a column called `unique_index_id` and its value is `2`. Not sure what that means.

Comment: @quakkels: Probably means that it's using the second column as key?

Comment: hmmm... that would be `pagename` instead of `pageID`. Can I just update that view to `1`?

Comment: @quakkels: The view is read-only.  Pretty sure you'll have to recreate the full-text index.